# Subgroups of M-groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, rt.representation-theory

Let $G$ be an M-group. Let $\chi$ be an irreducible character of $G$ and set $$A_{\chi} = 
\{ H\leq G\  |\  \exists \psi\in\textrm{Lin}(H): \psi^G = \chi\}$$
Since $G$ is an M-group, this set is non-empty for each $\chi\in\textrm{Irr}(G)$ (this is one way to define M-groups). Is it known whether $A_{\chi}$ always contains an M-group, or are there conditions known on $\chi$ that guarantee this (apart from $\chi$ being linear)?

Note:
A while ago I asked a question ([What subgroups of M-groups are guaranteed to be M-groups themselves?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55103/what-subgroups-of-m-groups-are-guaranteed-to-be-m-groups-themselves)) about what subgroups of M-groups that are themselves guaranteed to be M-groups. That question was probably too general to have a nice answer for the time being, and my edit to ask a more specific question may have been lost in the question itself.